# Invalid operation: shift of type float64

Tags: go, bit-shift

I'm facing a strange issue using the shift operator `<<` in Golang. In my final code, the shift value will be the absolute value of two integers. However, the Go package only defines the `Abs` function for `float64` values, so I will need to cast the parameters to use it, and then cast the result back to `uint`.

Finally, this value will be used as a `float64` parameter, so I cast it back to `float64` after that.

The problem is that the return value's cast does not seem to work as I expected...

```
var test float64

// all the following lines are working as expected
test = float64(1 << 10)
test = float64(1 << uint(10))
test = float64(1 << uint(float64(11-1)))
test = float64(1 << uint(-float64(1-11)))

// but this one does not: error at compilation
test = float64(1 << uint(math.Abs(10)))
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
invalid operation: 1 << uint(math.Abs(10)) (shift of type float64)
```

However, it seems that the cast operation alone works:

```
var test = uint(math.Abs(10))
fmt.Println(reflect.Kind(test))
// uint32
```

Is it a Golang issue ? A behaviour I did not find in the specifications ? A normal behaviour I simply don't understand ?

Here is a playground: http://play.golang.org/p/36a8r8CCYL

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators):

> The right operand in a shift expression must have unsigned integer type or be an untyped constant that can be converted to unsigned integer type. **If the left operand of a non-constant shift expression is an untyped constant, the type of the constant is what it would be if the shift expression were replaced by its left operand alone.**

So `float64(1 << uint(math.Abs(10)))` is basically the same as `float64(1) << uint(math.Abs(10))`, which produces an error, since one does not simply shift a float.

Comment: Firsly, ``reflect.Kind(1)`` is a type conversion, not a function call. What you need is ``reflect.ValueOf(1).Kind()``, which gives ``int``. Secondly, ``float64(1 << uint(float64(10)))`` works because it's a constant, not a variable. The spec quote is about **non-constant** shift expression.

Comment: @julienc the literal `1` is an *untyped constant*. The part of the spec Ainar-G quoted explains how the compiler pinpoints the type of an untyped constant. What `reflect` says as the type of an untyped constant depends on the context.